# Does Copy increase retain count value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

> I have read so many blogs and apple docs but some point still i am
>   confusing with all of above @property attributes weak,assign and copy
>   , so can any one please clear me about this.

**When to use Weak,copy and why in simple words.**

Comment: `copy` increases the __new__ object's retain count only; the current one's will remain untouched – but your question is ambiguous because because you have not specified _which object_ we should use as reference to answer your question; I highly doubt the accepted answer is either proper or useful.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Copy does't increase retain count , it's just copy value from the memory location and assign value. if you need the value of the object as it is at this moment, and you don't want that value to reflect any changes made by other owners of the object.

Comment: In Objective-C, copy _very often_ returns the original object, with the retain count increased by 1.

Comment: can u pls clarify it with example